# Lie Bracket and Multiplication

Tags: lie-algebras

I read [here](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node832.html) that the Lie bracket produces the notion of multiplication. Why is the Lie bracket for $GL(n)$ defined as $[A,B] = AB - BA $ and how is this like a "product" of the two matrices A and B?

Comment: The multiplication on the Lie Algebra of $GL(n)$ is induced by the Lie bracket...this is different than what your question insinuates as $GL(n)$ is a Lie Group with standard matrix multiplication as the multiplication operation.

Comment: The Lie bracket is not like a product.

Comment: It is a bilinear skew-symmetric product $A\circ B:=AB-BA$, usually written with (Lie) brackets.